# Are STM32 HID USB Drivers really that slow?

Tags: c, usb, stm32, hid, stm32f4

I have a project in which I need to transfer data over USB HID. I have performed some speed tests, and found the USB drivers painfully slow at less than 1kB/s (nowhere close to 64kB/s). Is it really a driver problem or something else. 
Has anyone achieved close to 64kB/s on STM32 HID?

Comment: Show us some code. Are you trying to send one byte at a time?

Comment: @TurboJ I am trying to send 64bytes per packet, which is the maximum.

Comment: What data are you trying to send over USB? As far I used it, it works as expected.

Comment: @tilz0R I have just setup a loopback HID device. I am sending a 64 byte packet and reading it back.

Comment: Sending from where, reading from where? Edit question with all the details you have possible.

Comment: @tilz0R I have a c# application. who sends and receives back

Comment: @tilz0R I am just using the sample code provided by ST, along with CUBE software

Answer (score 2):

Do you use Code of CubeMX for Custom USB HID? If so, please find file below:

**Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Libarary/Class/CustomHID/Src/
usbd_customhid.c**

you can see USBD_CUSTOM_HID_CfgDesc

The default interval is 20ms for both Tx and Rx.

```
  CUSTOM_HID_EPIN_SIZE, /*wMaxPacketSize: 2 Byte max */

  0x00,

  **0x20,   /* bInterval: Polling Interval (20 ms) */**

  ...

  CUSTOM_HID_EPOUT_SIZE,    /* wMaxPacketSize: 2 Bytes max  */

  0x00,

  **0x20,   /* bInterval: Polling Interval (20 ms) */**
```

you can change it to 1ms.